# how to run set of test cases from command prompt in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have below folder structure . Test cases are in folder F1 and F2
I want to run test cases from both the folders from CMD

```
like pybot --test [test2*,test5*] Folder1
```

but it gives me error

Folder1

```
F1
  test1
  test2
  test3    
F2
  test4
  test5
  test6
```

I have not found any solution for it.

Comment: Are you asking how to run 2 test suites from two different directories within the same line of the a pybot call in CMD?

Comment: @Goralight **yes**.

Comment: Then the below answer will do that for you :)

Comment: You say that F1 is a folder. If so, does that mean that `test1` is a file? Is it really named "test1", or is it named something like "test1.robot"? Or is F1 a robot test suite, and test1, test2, and test3 are test cases within the file? The wording in  your question is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misusing the `-t` option...

If you are asking how to call two different test suites (robot files) within two different directories - You simply just just call the file from the absolute path...

Here is an example:

```
pybot C:\TestSuites\Path\To\Your\First\TestSuite\TEST1.robot C:\TestSuite\And\Path\To\The\Other\One\TEST2.robot
```

Will fire off the test for the first suite, and then once complete, it will move on to the second test suite.

To reduce the amount of text, you can just navigate to the dir above all of these tests and then just step into it, like so:

```
pybot TEST1.robot Pathway\TEST2.robot
```

An example from my set up - I run a python script to change Dir and fire off the test suites which I specify. Could look into this if you want to make the task less painful.

Any questions please ask!